# How do we get schema information from a SqlDataReader in .net core 1.1?

Tags: .net-core

.net core. DataTable was deprecated, [so they came up with another api](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3423) for schema information: GetColumnSchema(). Trouble is, I'm looking at SqlDataReader in .net core 1.1. I can still see GetSchemaTable, but I can't access it's results. And I can't see it's replacement, GetColumnSchema(), despite having seen [sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8641) that seems to use this method. Has it been pulled? How do we get schema information from a SqlDataReader?

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.data.idatareader) the API documentation for IDataReader. GetSchemaTable() is there. It returns a DataTable, with which I can do nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to pull in this nuget package to get the extension method `GetColumnSchema()`

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.1.0" />
```

And obviously, add the `using`

```
using System.Data.Common;
```